# How to make data stable until we get back response in xhr?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When i send a simple `XMLHttpRequest()`

With my `asnyc` = 1

The HTML page I've loaded just blinks, why?

Can't it be stable until response is got?

I am using `responseText` to fetch contents.

My actual code is running at: http://fastchat.ga/chat

And also,

Sometimes **the request is not sent, why?**

Can anyone has an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all,

```
setInterval(showMsg,5000);
```

Please dont use strings for calling functions... That way is better.

Then, I don´t notice the blinking, but if the field is a boolean, you should use a boolean instead of using 1 (it's not a falsy value, but it's not a true).
What I'd recommend, is to avoid using the argument, given that it's default value is true.

Good luck

Comment: Also, what about then when sometimes my request isn't sent? Help.

Comment: showMsg, because setInterval will evaluate the function you'll send. If you use showMsg(), you are sending the results of the function, instead of the function itself.

To debug your problem, you should 
`console.log("I'm about to send a request");` on showMsg, and then check the network of your debugger (on your browser) if there's a new request, of even if the latest request has ended.

Hope it's useful

Comment: Nice! Sorry for late :)